# Start Chrome with a URL with options incognito mode and maximized tab IN BATCH

Tags: google-chrome, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

This command line opens an incognito tab and connects to the URL in environment variable *%url%*:

```
start chrome --incognito %url%
```

This maximizes the tab and connects to the %url%.

```
start chrome %url% /MAX
```

But as soon as I try to combine them, like this,

```
start chrome --incognito %url% /MAX
```

The `/MAX` option does not work.

How can I properly combine their functions?

Answer (score 8):

> How can I properly combine their functions?

You may be using `/max` in the wrong position. `/max` is an option to `start`, not `chrome`. You also appear to be leaving off the (in most cases) necessary leading set of double-quotes (`""`) for `start`. So your `start` command should look like:

*ex. incognito_chrome.bat*

```
set url=plus.net

start "" /max chrome --incognito %url%
```

Also be aware that if `chrome` isn't really `chrome.exe` (e.g. it's `chrome.bat`), this could be eating your `/max` option (in this example, `/max` would be used on the command window spawned by `chrome.bat`, not Chrome [`chrome.exe`] itself). If this is the case, you should use the full path to `chrome.exe` rather than just `chrome`.

*References*

- *[start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)* (ss64 documentation)

Comment: What is *"ex."*? *Executable*? *EXE file*? *Example*? *For example*? Something else?

Comment: `ex.` is intended to be [short for example](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ex).

Answer (score 5):

The `/MAX` is in the wrong position, but it's not strictly necessary because Chrome has a command line option to start maximized.

You can use the command line argument directly:

```
set url=superuser.com
start chrome --start-maximized --incognito %url%
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want by involving PowerShell in your script. PowerShell provides more control over the process start parameters.

Here is a working example of a batch file you can use.

**StartChrome.bat**

```
SET URL=plus.net

powershell -c "start-process chrome.exe -WindowStyle Maximized -ArgumentList ""%URL% --incognito"""
```

Comment: `SET URL=plus.net
powershell -c "start-process chrome.exe -WindowStyle Maximized -ArgumentList ""%URL% --incognito"""` I executed this code, but the tap wasn't maximized.

Comment: @shiftdel sorry to hear that, but did you put it in a batch file as I showed? Seems you have it all in one line, but maybe that's just the comment formatting. I tested it and it definitely works!

Answer (score 0):

Try this PowerShell code using the Windows API:

```
$url = "URL"
chrome.exe --incognito "$url"
$max = 3
$winapi_code = @'
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
'@
Add-Type -MemberDefinition $winapi_code -Name NativeMethods -Namespace Win32
$hWnd = (Get-Process -Name chrome).MainWindowHandle | Where-Object {$_ -ne 0}
[Win32.NativeMethods]::ShowWindow($hWnd, $max) | Out-Null
```

Comment: Downvoter, please explain the downvote, as this code is tested and worked without flaws.